# Compare dates same column mySQL Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a 'tasks' table that looks like the following:
[image]

I need to calculate the start date offset for each record; I need to calculate how many days after the min/lowest start date the start date for each record is.

I am doing this in Laravel 4.  The table is mySQL.  I would really prefer a Laravel query, but I can probably also include raw mySQL.

My query (it selects some other things, too) doesn't work

```
    $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->select(array(DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, MIN(start), start) AS offset"), DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start, end) AS length"), 'user_id', 'name', 'desc','start','end','finished'))->where('temp_id', $id)->orderBy('start')->get();
```

"MIN(start)" for the self compare seems to be the problem.  How do I calculate how many days after the min start date the start date for each record is?

Comment: I may be completely off-base here, but isn't `MIN()` an aggregate function to find the smallest value in a group of records? If so, I don't think it would make sense when used on a `DATETIME` field in a single row.

Comment: I cannot speak to anything Laravel, but it is common @TimLewis. See this Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32030445/1816093) that I wrote up, for instance, but using `max` not `min`

Comment: @Drew Laravel's query builder is a wrapper for basic SQL syntax, and looking at your answer provides some insight. I'll write up a quick answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to solve the incorrect usage of `MIN(start)` on a non-aggregated result set.

Option one: Save the variable for the minimum date and use that in your query:

```
$min_date = DB::table("tasks")->selectRaw("id, MIN(start) AS min")->groupBy("id")->first();
echo $min_date->min; // 2015-08-15 00:00:00, assuming my syntax was correct.

$tasks = DB::table('tasks')
->select(array(DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, ".$min_date->min.", start) AS offset"), DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start, end) AS length"), 'user_id', 'name', 'desc','start','end','finished'))
->where('temp_id', $id)
->orderBy('start')
->get();
```

Option two: Use a subquery in the select:

```
$tasks = DB::table('tasks')
->select(array(DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(start) FROM tasks), start) AS offset"), DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start, end) AS length"), 'user_id', 'name', 'desc','start','end','finished'))
->where('temp_id', $id)
->orderBy('start')
->get();
```

Note on `MIN()` usage: It can be used without aggregating results, but only returns a single row, unless used in a subquery.

Examples:

```
SELECT start FROM tasks; /*6 Rows*/
SELECT MIN(start) FROM tasks; /*1 Row*/
SELECT MIN(start), start FROM tasks; /*1 Row*/
SELECT (SELECT (MIN(start) FROM tasks) AS min_start, start FROM tasks; /*6 Rows*/
```

The last example will return the results from each row alongside the minimum `start` found in `tasks`. Hope this helped clear your issue up. Either option 1 or option 2 should help, but leave a comment in you need help with anything else.

Comment: I think this is what self-join or subqueries are for.  I did option #1 with two queries but I did have to change the quotes around $min_date->low

DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '".$low_date->start."' , start) AS offset"),